# Need suggestion for insertion of two records in mysql at same time

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am working on auction site where user can bid and won auctions. In my case auction ends when bidding ends (number of bids set from admin). So i need suggestion about the final bid. What if the final bid is placed by 2 different users exactly at same time?

Right now when someone click on bid button, i am sending request to ajax and inserting record there. The only way i know to do it, is to check from database and that how many bids are left and insert accordingly (by allowing one user), but again there may occur an exception if the time is exactly same. Meanwhile i don't want to waste time in querying database again there, as it will delay in bidding and can create more trouble.

Here is my php code which make bids.

`$cid = $_GET['cid'];`

```
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$placeBid = $obj->insert("bids",array("productid"=>$pid,"userid"=>$uid,"coinsid"=>$cid,"type"=>$type,"date"=>$date));

if($placeBid)
{
  //if bid is successfull, update the status of coins in coins table.
  $obj->update("coins","status=? where id=?",array(0,$cid));
  //Also update bid counts in product table, to ensure the bids placed on specific product
  if($type == 'paid')
  {
      $obj->update("products","bidscount=bidscount+1 where id=?",array($pid));
   }
  //check if still coins are left with user

            //get bid coins for current user.
    $bidCoins = $obj->select("coins","*","userid=? and status=?",array($userid,1));

    if($bidCoins)
    {

        $coinsHtml = '<a href="#"class="close"/>X</a>

            <div class="coins_popup"> 

            <h3>Select your coins box and bid</h3>';

        foreach((array)$bidCoins as $bidCoinsR)
        {
            $b = ($bidCoinsR['type'] == 'free')?"(B)":"";

                if($bidCoinsR['type'] == 'free')
                {
                    $type = 0;
                }
                else if($bidCoinsR['type'] == 'paid')
                {
                    $type = 1;
                }
            $coinsHtml .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="placeBid('.$bidCoinsR["id"].','.$bidCoinsR["userid"].','.$type.')"><span>'.$bidCoinsR["amount"].$b.'</span></a>';
        }
        $coinsHtml .= '<input type="hidden" id="product_id" value="" name="product_id">';
        echo $coinsHtml .= '</div>';

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'You have no more coins available';
    }

 }
```

Can you please suggest me the best way. thanks

Comment: What version of MySql are you using?  A very generic suggestion would be to lock the table when inserting a bid.  It would eliminate any possibility of the race condition you described.  Have you read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: hmm, haven't used it before. I will look into locking. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A very generic suggestion would be to lock the table when inserting a bid. It would eliminate any possibility of the race condition you described. Have you read this:

[dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)